# How to rekey numerical array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array `$matrix_part`, containing arrays, and I want to rekey the inner keys to start at 1.

I am trying to code below but it doesn't work - it just stores the new array identically.

```
$temp_matrix = array();
foreach ($matrix_part as $k => $v){
$temp_matrix[$k++] = $v;
}
$matrix_part = $temp_matrix;
```

Source array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 163
            [1] => 23
            [2] => 97
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 163
            [1] => 23
            [2] => 97
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 163
            [1] => 23
            [2] => 97
        )
)
```

Desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 163
            [2] => 23
            [3] => 97
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 163
            [2] => 23
            [3] => 97
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 163
            [1] => 23
            [3] => 97
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($a as $outer_k => $outer_v) {
    for ($i = count($outer_v) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $outer_v[$i+1] = $outer_v[$i];
    }
    unset($outer_v[0]);
    $a[$outer_k] = $outer_v;
}
```

where $a is your input array

Answer (score 2):

Try use:
instead of this:

```
  $temp_matrix[$k++] = $v;
```

do this:

```
 $temp_matrix[++$k] = $v;
```

Answer (score 2):

This maybe?

```
$input = array(
    array(163, 23, 97),
    array(163, 23, 97),
    array(163, 23, 97),
);

$output = array_map(function ($innerArray) {
    return array_combine(range(1, sizeof($innerArray)), $innerArray);
}, $input);

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could do something like ...

```
    foreach ($matrix as $k=>$v) {
        foreach ($v as $k2=>$v2) {
            $tmp_arr[$k][$k2+1] = $v2;
        }
    }
    $matrix = $tmp_arr;
```